# Prevent browser from downloading file served as FileStreamResult in ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API controller that returns mp4 file as `FileStreamResult` like this:

```
var fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            
return new FileStreamResult(fs, "video/mp4") { EnableRangeProcessing = true };
```

Then I use this endpoint as `<video>` tag source to play it back.

If I take the url of the endpoint and navigate to it directly from browser, it opens the default video player and the file can be downloaded from there.

Is there a way to prevent file from being downloaded directly from the browser, by directly navigating to the link?

Comment: `Then I use this endpoint as tag source to play it back` how are you doing this?

Comment: @Chetan, I assign src property of  video tag to a url of the endpoint. It does work fine btw. as described in the question, the problem is that when i go the link directly, browser allows me to download the file. Thanks!